# Want to use comment in html embeded with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my JavaScript file code and I want to comment some html tag please suggest me how can I Comment to this html code.

This is sample code of JavaScript I want to comment One div

I have tried `//`, i have tried `<\!--..-->` i have tried `/\*..*/` and it does not work.

```
(function ($) {
    $.prettyPhoto = {
        version: '3.1.2'
    };
    $.fn.prettyPhoto = function (pp_settings) {
        pp_settings = jQuery.extend({
            animation_speed: 'fast',
            slideshow: 5000,
            autoplay_slideshow: false,
            opacity: 0.80,
            show_title: true,
            allow_resize: true,
            default_width: 500,
            default_height: 344,
            counter_separator_label: '/',
            theme: 'pp_default',
            horizontal_padding: 20,
            hideflash: false,
            wmode: 'opaque',
            autoplay: true,
            modal: false,
            deeplinking: true,
            overlay_gallery: true,
            keyboard_shortcuts: true,
            changepicturecallback: function () {},
            callback: function () {},
            ie6_fallback: true,
            markup: '<div class="pp_pic_holder"><div class="ppt">&nbsp;</div><div class="pp_top"><div class="pp_left"></div><div class="pp_middle"></div><div class="pp_right"></div></div><div class="pp_content_container"><div class="pp_left"><div class="pp_right"><div class="pp_content"><div class="pp_loaderIcon"></div><div class="pp_fade"><a href="#" class="pp_expand" title="Expand the image">Expand</a><div class="pp_hoverContainer"><a class="pp_next" href="#">next</a><a class="pp_previous" href="#">previous</a></div><div id="pp_full_res"></div><div class="pp_details"><div class="pp_nav"><a href="#" class="pp_arrow_previous">Previous</a><p class="currentTextHolder">0/0</p><a href="#" class="pp_arrow_next">Next</a></div><p class="pp_description"></p>{pp_social}<a class="pp_close" href="#">Close</a></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="pp_bottom"><div class="pp_left"></div><div class="pp_middle"></div><div class="pp_right"></div></div></div>*
```

Comment: In your keyboard, there is a so called `Enter`

Comment: I don't think you expressed clearly enough. Comment on what html tag?

Comment: I want to comment one div tag like 
<!--<div> Content ..</div> -->

Comment: You want to add an HTML comment into the string value assigned to the `markup` option?

Comment: yes...how can I add comment to <div class="ppt">&nbsp;</div> tag

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For Div Tag you have to use `<\!-- Div and Content --\>`

Like this:

```
<!--
<\!--<div> Content </div> --\>
-->
```

Comment: I want comment for div tag in html

Comment: its .js file not html

Comment: In markup you are setting static content. And it will work like this only.

Comment: Yes. It will work. As you are sending static content you need have inline comments within the block. i.e. ending up on this. pretty sure.